# Class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMapperProperties' is marked deprecated?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created a sample Spring Boot 1.2.2 project using the Spring Initializr (http://start.spring.io/) and inside the auto-created application class:

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I get this warning:

> Class
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMapperProperties' is
>   marked deprecated

Why? How to get rid of it?

Comment: What have you configured in `application.properties` or `application.yaml`?

Comment: `application.properties` is empty, don't have any `application.yaml`, Spring Boot changed since 1.2.1, doesn't it?

Comment: It is strange, but I started editing the code and the warning disappeared...What could it be due to? I am using Spring Boot together with Vaadin and the Vaadin Spring Boot addon...

Comment: @AndyWilkinson The warning seams to reappear each time I update my maven `pom.xml` dependencies

Comment: Same problem appeared to me after upgraded STS to latest version (3.6.4.RELEASE).. I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.2.RELEASE.. any solution?

Comment: Nothing yet, I am still facing this annoying warning each time I update the Maven's `pom.xml`. Anyway, to get rid of it, I am using the Vaadin framework together with Spring and as I create a new UI class and start edit it the warning disappeares. But then it reappears again as soon as I update the `pom.xml`. Really annoying... Hope the guys of Spring fix this issue...

Comment: There appears to be a Jira ticket marked as a minor bug for this issue - https://jira.spring.io/browse/IDE-1366

Comment: @tonix feel free to accept the answer, so this issue it is visible that this issue is solved (soon). :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can safely ignore this warning as it will be fixed in [IDE-1366](https://jira.spring.io/browse/IDE-1366) for release STS 3.7.0.